# append access table based on presence of a character

Tags: ms-access, append, conditional-statements

I have an Access table "results" that contains assay lab results for different analytes. I have a second table "results_final" that will contain all the cleaned up values.  Cleaning the results occurs in scenarios such as different labs providing results in different ways when analytes are not detected, for example with the use of the "<0.0001" (less than) others use an "X" and so forth.  I want to appended the results_final table so that the results for analytes that are detected are kept the same and those that are not detected are changed to "-999999" so that they are consistent (and numerical) in the "results_final" table.  This might occur across multiple cells for multiple records.

I have use a simple query to identify records that would qualify such as
'''select * From results where result_value '*<*' '''

Where I am stuck is using the append to update the 'Results_final' table to insert the desired value.
This will be an ongoing requirement so ideally I need to be able to repeat/automate the process easily.

What is the best approach to change/append all the records that meet the specific requirements?

Comment: Why copy records to another table? Why not just use filtered query? Why not just modify data in original table? An expression can replace values in same field or update another field set as number type. How many different values need to be fixed? Your query does not select records where value is "X". How is data entered into table to begin with? Why not fix it at that time?

Comment: All the data is imported from either csv or excel.  It would be easier to easier to fix everything outside the database, however, there needs to be an auditable trail of changes within the database.  there are about 4 different ways the data might be stored <0.0001. X, XX or -0.0001.  the number of decimal places may vary depending on the analyte.  I am open to suggestions that either updates into a new column of the same table or appended in a different table,  A new table is being used as additional information is being included such as the technique used and the name of the lab being used

Comment: Isn't test method and lab already in data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably just update field in same table. Something like:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE table SET field1=-999999 " & _ 
                  " WHERE field0 IN('<0.0001', 'X', 'XX', '-0.0001')"
```

Or

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE table SET field1=-999999 " & _ 
                  " WHERE Not IsNumeric(field0)"
```

Or

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE table Set field1=IIf(IsNumeric(field0), field0, -999999) WHERE field1 Is Null"
```

Comment: Thanks, with a bit of tweaking I was able to implement the bottom solution